# PHP - store input variable for static reuse

Tags: php

There are some inputs, and there is a function. The function requires these inputs, and the inputs are user-given. But, the buttons that fire the function and the input submission form are two different buttons. So, when the user presses "`submit`" to store his variables, the variables are stored fine. But, when he presses the "calculate" button (which fires the function), php says "`undefined index`" because it reads the $`_POST` of that input again and again.

If I disable `register_globals`, it does not show '`undefined index`' but these values are 0 again.

If I use another file just to store these values and then redirect back to the page where the function button is, there is a redirect loop, `require_once` does not work.

What is the way to store the inputs in such way that they can be used again and again in functions and whatsoever? No databases, I need a way to store them in variables.

edit: the form: `<label for="asdf">enter value:</label> <input type="text" id="asdf" name="asdf" value="<?php echo $asdf;?>" />`

storing the value:
$asdf=$_POST['asdf'];

then I need to write $asdf in the function with the updated value that the user gave through the html form. How to do it? Cannot be much simpler

Comment: Please show some code and what you have tried.

Comment: you could store them as session variables

Comment: @nomistic can you give me an example? The values are numeric values (int) by the way.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp or http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: No, @gamwtoshiston, please show what you have tried so far. We would like you to put effort into researching your questions because this question is too broad as written. Databases, cookies, sessions, globals, static files....  you get the point.

Comment: `$_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var'];`

Comment: @gamwtoshiston you should look up a tutorial.  This site is not for that purpose.  If you have specific problems once you have tried, then demonstrate these here, and people might help, but you are expected to do some research first before coming here.  Sessions will likely help you.   search "php session tutorial"

Comment: @nomistic the values are inputted by the user in HTML forms, no access to php code, so how can they be stored in $_session ???

Comment: I suggest you might want to research how post variables work

Comment: Do you know @tototororo? This sounds a lot like a question he asked a couple of hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037815/php-storing-input-to-static-variables-knowingly-vague-title

Answer (score 1):

I would just store them in the session. That way they, they can be used across php scripts, but are not stored in the long-term. Here's an example:

form.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="store.php">
    <input type="text" name="x" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['x'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="y" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['y'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<form action="calculate.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

store.php

```
<?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["x"] = $_POST['x']; // substitute your input here
  $_SESSION["y"] = $_POST['y']; // substitute your input here
?>
```

calculate.php

```
<?php
  // Start the session
  session_start();
  $result = $_SESSION["x"] * $_SESSION["y"];
  echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Let's say in store.php , how can these be stored in sessions while in a form? Can the output of the form be with $_SESSION instead of $_POST?

Comment: great, this sounds like a solution, will return with results

Comment: You can then use the $_SESSION variables in your form too.

Comment: Added form.php and made it as simple as possible... But I agree with previous comments. You really should be looking for a tutorial for this.

Comment: @BakerStreet: you want to echo $_SESSION in the form.php

Comment: yup. echo out the session variables

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to store them in variables. Every request to your server is a new request. 
You could store the variables in a cookie/session or give them back after pushing the first button and store them in a hidden field in your html form. Or store them in a file on your server.

Comment: @gamwtoshiston edit your original question and add the sample code there.