# i m not able to store the input data of form on the redirect page ...both form has same input data form

Tags: php

this is `playingcards-quote.php`

```
        <div class='container'>
            <label for='name' >First Name*: </label><br/>
            <input type='text' name='name' id='name'  maxlength="50" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); 

        }?>" /><br />
            <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error' style="font-size: 12px;"></span>

        </div>
```

The redirect page has same input `form data` as `playingcards-quote.php`

```
      <div class='container'>
            <label for='name' >First Name*: </label><br/>
            <input type='text' name='name' id='name'  maxlength="50" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); 

        }?>" /><br />
            <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error' style="font-size: 12px;"></span>

        </div>
```

I m not able to store the input data of form on the redirect page ...both form has same input  data form 
I have two page .both having same input form value 
When i submit the form value of one page the same value should be seen in redirect form page

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're describing.  Can you elaborate on the problem?  What "redirect" are you talking about?  This just looks like the same code twice, what's the difference?

Comment: If I get it right he wants when a user submits first form to redirect to a new page with the second form and set the field from the first form

Comment: @David i want a input form  value shoul not lose the value even after redirecting the another page . my 1st form and   redirecting page  form is exact same form .i want to preserve the value in the from 1st form to 2nd form

Comment: @l.g.karolos my first form is getting stored but after redirecting to redirecting page the input data loses it value

Comment: @Neetuyadav: How is it "redirecting"?  Where do you pass along or store the values?

Comment: If you store the data you could just fetch them from the database for the second form

Comment: @David first form page is playingcardsquote.php which has one input value name it has action as thankyou.php when i click submit button of the form it is going to thankyou.php but my input data is lost at thankyou.php form

Comment: @l.g.karolos  i m  not using mysql or database at all .i have no mysql code in my form

Comment: you can use $_SESSION right?

Comment: @Neetuyadav: That's not a "redirect", it's just a form post.  Show the form and show the code that's using the form values.  We can only help with code we can see.

Comment: @David i m talking about $_SESSION ...how i can use the $_SESSION on the redirecting page so that i cannot lose the 1st form input value

Comment: @Neetuyadav: There's no mention of session in the question.  Did you try a Google search for something like "PHP session example"?  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  What does *any of this* have to do with the code you're showing in the question.  Nothing about what you're asking is clear or answerable.  Be specific about the actual problem you're encountering.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava if i want to store name .how can i use it with session .how to write full code i want to store name

Comment: I guess this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31038876/5588347) should help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this .hope this gives you an idea. unless I misunderstood

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="pass2.php" method="Post">

    <input type='text' name='name' id='name'  maxlength="50" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <form/>
    <body/>
    </html>
```

Your Form 2 which is "pass2.php"

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<input type='text' name='name' id='name'  maxlength="50" value=<?php echo $_POST["name"]?> />


<body/>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you .That all i was in need